# Will this rod rotate or remain stable?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

Sorry I have to ask such a basic question. It's basically A level Mechanics. I don't have any book and don't know how to find the answer quickly.

Mass is distributed uniformly on the rod. 30N is the weight acting vertically downward. 14N and 16N vertically upward forces  are applied at the opposite ends. 14N + 16N =30N so it should take care of the weight. I am confused whether the system will be stable or be rotating. I think it should because when the moment is calculated with respect to the middle point it is non-zero. I am just not sure and don't know how to make the point rigorously. 
Will greatly appreciate if someone answer and better link to useful resources. Thanks in  advance. :)

Comment: Why are you expected to answer this if you don't have any resource to consult: either book, website, teacher, or fellow students?  You don't need to "find" the answer, you need to LEARN about torques/moments.

Comment: My younger brother asked me to help him over phone with a slightly more complicated problem (but it ultimately amounted to this). I haven't studied mechanics after high school so my memory is not fresh. I can recognize formula and use them .. and they are easy to find in the internet. But this particular point was confusing me, so I googled for free books on mechanics without luck. and finally   decided to post here.

Comment: Check out this site: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html

Answer (score 3):

The center of mass will not move, as the total force is zero, however the rod will rotate, as there is a nonzero torque (around the center, counter-clockwise is positive direction).

$$
M=16\frac{1}{2}-14\frac{1}{2}=1~\text{N m}
$$